# Manage local nuget repository

Tags: nuget

I have a local nuget repository, where I would like to browse the packages, is there some kind of tool for this?

We have a project that is pushed to my local repository, when we have new updates we just push a new version. We needed to branch the project and therefor we pushed this new version. But I somehow didn't change the package id. So now I need to browse and remove this package, change the id and push it again?

So my questions is, is there any tool I can use to manage my local nuget packages?

Comment: What type of repository? Is it a simple file share or are you using one of the NuGet gallery web apps?

Comment: We have a local NuGet gallery hosted on our IIS. I've tried to delete the repo from the console too. But i get a 404 everytime.

Comment: I can see the packages we have in our gallary with the list command, so it's wierd why I can't delete. That's why I hoped for some GUI interface or other way to manage the gallary.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any 'tool' to accomplish this. However, you can manually remove the .nupkg file for the latest (bad) version from your packages folder.

Since you are running the repo from IIS, you can check your web.config file for the following key:

```
    <add key="packagesPath" value="C:\folder\folderHoldingNupkgFiles" />
```

This will tell you where you .nupkg files are stored. Go there and find the latest version that you published and remove it. Afterward, change the id, etc, and republish as the new package.

Once this happens, you should see the original/previous version from before, as well as you new/branched version.